# Validation using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, textbox

How to created textbox dynamically , when i click add button.

after i put the input field in the text box.

how to validate the dynamically created textbox using javascript or jquery.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Adding and Removing Text Boxes Dynamically</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var intTextBox=0;
//FUNCTION TO ADD TEXT BOX ELEMENT 
function addElement(){
  intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
  var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
  var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
  newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Text "+intTextBox+": <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "'    name='" + intTextBox + "'/>"; 
  contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
}

  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Demo of Adding and Removing Text Box Dynamically using JavaScript</p>
    <p><a href="javascript:addElement();" >Add</a> 
       <a href="javascript:removeElement();" >Remove</a>
    </p>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <input type="button" value="submit"/>
  </body>
  </html>
```

after when i click submit button all textbox validation must be done....

Comment: what do you mean by "validate the textbox" ? to check that it exists ? to validate the input the user added into it ? what do you mean by "dynamically create textbox - dynamically when what event occurs ?

Comment: yes validate the dynamically created text box.... is it possible?

Comment: sure, when you create the textbox assign it with ID and then use getElementById() to make sure it exists

Comment: dynamically means when i click add button the textbox added to the form....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to copy this and test. And let's tell me that is as you need.**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Adding and Removing Text Boxes Dynamically</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var intTextBox = 0 ;//FUNCTION TO ADD TEXT BOX ELEMENT 
function addElement(){
    intTextBox += 1
  var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
  var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
  newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Text "+intTextBox%x+": <input type='text' id='%2+ intTextBox + "'    name='" + intTextBox + "' />"; 
  contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
}

function removeElement(){
    var element = document.getElementById("strText"+intTextBox);
    console.log(element);
    while (element.firstChild) {
        element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
    }
    intTextBox -=1;
}
</script>
</head><body>
<p>Demo of Adding and Removing Text Box Dynamically using JavaScript</p>
<p><a href="javascript:addElement()" >Add</a> 
   <a href="javascript:removeElement();" >Remove</a>
</p>
<div id="content"></div>
<input type="button" value="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

See more at [My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pFK4/)

Note : working with FireFox & Chrome

Answer (score 1):

create textbox:

```
var textbox = $('<input></input>');
textbox.setAttr(type, 'text');
```

add to container:

```
$('#button').onclick(function() {
    $('#container').append(textbox);
});
```

validate:

```
$('#submit').onclick(function() {
   if(!$('#textbox').val()) {
      alert('input empty');
   }
});
```

Comment: this is only used for single text box.. but i ask for dynamically created text box validation..

Comment: function addElement()
{
intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Text "+intTextBox+": <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "' name='" + intTextBox + "'/>";
contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
}

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). The [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) shows that is can validate textboxes.

Comment: <script>function addElement()
{
intTextBox = intTextBox + 1;
var contentID = document.getElementById('content');
var newTBDiv = document.createElement('div');
newTBDiv.setAttribute('id','strText'+intTextBox);
newTBDiv.innerHTML = "Text "+intTextBox+": <input type='text' id='" + intTextBox + "' name='" + intTextBox + "'/>";
contentID.appendChild(newTBDiv);
}</script>

Comment: function addSense(sense){ comment.content += sense; }

Answer (score 1):

that's alot of questions rolled into one.  You can create and insert elements in jquery with code like the following:

```
$('<input />', {type : 'text'}).appendTo($(body));
```

As far as validation is concerned, it would depend on when you want to do it. on keypress, on submit, on blur, etc.  If you want a blanket validate for all inputs you'll need to delegate it to some parent element since these textboxes are created after the page is loaded:

```
$('body').delegate('input','keyup', function(){
    /*Do stuff*/
});
```

But you could also attach the validation when you create the element if it needs to be specific to the field you create.

```
$('<input />', {type : 'text'}).bind('keyup', function(){ 
    /*Do stuff*/
}).appendTo($(body));
```

I hope that steers you in the right direction.   Good luck